# How to add a version number to a set of data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some data in a SQL Server table ...

```
ClientID  DecisionID
60043     1466338   
60043     1475880   
60043     1480017   
104563    1468452
106454    1475922   
106454    1475922
```

and I've been asked to add a "version" column for each decision for each client, so e.g. client 60043 would have version 1, 2 and 3, like so ...

```
ClientID  DecisionID  Version
60043     1466338       V1
60043     1475880       V2
60043     1480017       V3
104563    1468452       V1
106454    1475922       V1
106454    1475922       V2
```

I can add a column with an `UPDATE` statement, and then I could likely write some C# code to iterate through populating the new column, but I'm sure there's a better way in SQL, but I've no idea how to even start ... *any help/pointers would be gratefully accepted*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to add version to results (not actually create column) then:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      clientID INT ,
      decisionID INT
    );
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 60043, 1466338 ),
        ( 60043, 1475880 ),
        ( 60043, 1480017 ),
        ( 104563, 1468452 ),
        ( 106454, 1475922 ),
        ( 106454, 1475922 )

SELECT  clientID ,
        decisionID ,
        'V'
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY clientID 
                                   ORDER BY decisionID DESC ) AS NVARCHAR(10))
FROM    @t
```

You can use similar way to do update:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      clientID INT ,
      decisionID INT ,
      ver VARCHAR(20)
    );
INSERT  INTO @t
        ( clientID, decisionID )
VALUES  ( 60043, 1466338 ),
        ( 60043, 1475880 ),
        ( 60043, 1480017 ),
        ( 104563, 1468452 ),
        ( 106454, 1475922 ),
        ( 106454, 1475922 );

WITH    c AS ( SELECT   clientID ,
                        decisionID ,
                        'V'
                        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY clientID 
                            ORDER BY decisionID DESC ) AS NVARCHAR(10)) v
               FROM     @t
             )
    UPDATE  tab
    SET     ver = v
    FROM    @t tab
            INNER JOIN c ON tab.clientID = c.clientID
                            AND tab.decisionID = c.decisionID

SELECT  *
FROM    @t;
```

Comment: Jānis I was actually looking to add the data to the table, after creating a new column

Comment: @SteveC - The usual SQL philosophy is don't store that which you can compute - if you compute it during retrieval, it's *always right*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was thinking this, but what if one of the versions if removed from the database. This would then adjust all version numbers

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with you, except the SQL philosophy is trumped by the *customer is always right* philosophy

Comment: @SteveC in that case my solution is not for you (you can use it for update though). You want de-normalization and "pay" at the time of "Insert", instead of "Select" part. that is perfectly fine if that is what you need..

Answer (score 0):

First write an ALTER script to add the Version column to the table.

Next write an UPDATE script to set the Version depending on your conditions.